# Is there a way to find all interactions with a specific user?

Tags: support, data-explorer

**Is there a query that allows me to find all the posts where there are interactions between me and another user?**

By "interactions" I mean:

- Their answers to / comments on my questions.
- My answers to / comments on their questions.
- Any comments on other posts that include `@user` (by me) or `@me` (by the user).

The query is expected to return just the links of the posts, not a direct link to the comment/answer.

Comment: You can probably start off with [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/122341/where-did-i-meet-this-user) and modify it to your liking.

Comment: @rene For some reason, this takes a very long time to execute. Also, the query in Glorfindel's comment is closer to my requirements; if there's a duplicate question that points to that query, I'm happy to close this one as a duplicate to it. If not, Glorfindel may feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel Feel free to post this as an answer or close as duplicate if you're aware of a dup. [I couldn't find one that contains this query](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*data.stackexchange.com%2F*%2F122341%2F*%22).

Comment: See the duplicate, which covers your requirements exactly, with the exception that direct links are given. You’d have to fork it to return only post links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two bullet points seem to be supported by the SEDE query 
[Where did I meet this user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/122341/where-did-i-meet-this-user)
:

> Questions at which the two users met
>   One of the following cases happened:
>
> - one posted a question, the other one an answer
> - both posted two concurrent answers
> - one commented on the other one's post
> - both commented on the same post
>
> So we don't involve cases when e.g. one user comments answer on the other user's question.

It will give too much hits for the third bullet point, but you might be able to filter them out by hand, or [fork the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/122341) so that it will meet your needs.

Comment: My versiion covers all the requirements: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/853808/have-they-met